# Выбрать нужный <div> javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая структура:

```
<div id="content"> 
   <div class="class"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom"> 
   <div class="class"></div>
</div>
```

Есть скрипт

```
$ ( function() {
$ ( ".class" ).dialog({ ......
...
```

Как сделать, чтобы скрипт затрагивал только .class, который находится внутри #bottom ?

Comment: Не работает. 
Если прописать просто $('.class') работает со всеми div'ами этого класса на странице, если добавить что-то вперед, не работает вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен [вложенный селектор](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/descendant) -

```
$ ( "#bottom .class" ).dialog({ ......
```

Comment: Не работает. Если прописать просто $('.class') работает со всеми div'ами этого класса на странице, если добавить что-то вперед, не работает вообще. –